# Instructions on how to edit DNS for major DNS providers and registrars

Tags: untagged

I need to direct my customers to make a DNS change, but they all have different registrars.  It is next to impossible to create a single set of instructions that applies to all of them.

Does anyone know of (or have) instructions that apply to most people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maintains a pretty large list of [instructions](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?topic=1611273) for setting up Google Apps for various DNS providers. Those pages are copyrighted by Google, so you can't just copy them outright, but at least it could give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Found another one by Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/online/help/en-us/helphowto/d9214059-ca8c-4452-9ee8-d2e49c5ad515.htm